# Extrema on $D:=\{(a,b)^T \in \mathbb{R}^2: \|(a,b)^T\|_2=1\}$ of $f((a,b)^T)=5a^2+7b^2-14ab$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization

$f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$

$f((a,b)^T)=5a^2+7b^2-14ab$

How can I determine the extrema (minima and maxima) on $D:=\{(a,b)^T \in \mathbb{R}^2: \|(a,b)^T\|_2=1\}$?

My play is to write $b=\pm\sqrt{1-x^2}$ and then look where $f_a$ and $f_b$ are $0$ and then use the second derivative test.

But am I allowed to this? Because I am afraid I can't just differentiate on $D$ itself. But I would arrive at the correct result when I compare it to wolframalpha.

Can this be done like this or is this wrong and how else can it be done?

(We haven't heard about Lagrange multipliers yet if that makes any difference)

Comment: Did you hear about the fact that in optimization with equality constraint the gradients are parallel at the optimal point? Otherwise set $a=\cos t$, $b=\sin t$.

Comment: @A.Γ.
No I haven't. So I should write $f$ in polar coordinates with radius $r=1$? How would I continue?

Comment: Well, after that you can optimize the function of one variable (angle) in the interval $[0,2\pi]$ without constraints (setting derivative zero etc)